# Java 8 - Best way to separate a list into 3 different lists

Tags: java, list, split, java-stream

Input:

1. I have a List abcLines which has all types of lines of type A or B or C.
2. I also have a readymade List of type A (aLines).

I want to separate the big list (abcLines) into 3 different lists (aLines, bLines and cLines).

```
class ABCLine {
  int id;
  Object tlId; // value of this field is false (if the line type is A or C) or the value of this field is a List (if the type is B)
}


    List<ABCLine> bLines = new ArrayList<ABCLine>();
    List<ABCLine> cLines = new ArrayList<ABCLine>();
    
    abcLines.forEach(abcLine -> {
        if (abcLine.tlId instanceof List) {
            bLines.add(abcLine);
            abcLines.remove(abcLine);
        } else {
            aLines.forEach(aLine -> {
               if (aLine.id.equals(abcLine.id)) {
                   abcLines.remove(abcLine);                       
               }
            });
        }
    });
    
    cLines = abcLines;
```

How can I write this code using Java 8 streams in a better way?

Comment: So this is working code? If yes posibly codereview be a beter place to get an answer.

Comment: You're removing from `abcLines` while you're iterating over it. That's bound to go wrong.

Comment: Three `stream().filter(..).collect(..)` will do the job. Iterating over a list is extremely fast, and the less forks in your code the faster it will be, so it may be easier and faster to just stream your list three times.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `Collectors.partitioningBy` to separate the lines.

```
    List<ABCLine> aLines = new ArrayList<>(); //Ready made aline list
    List<ABCLine> abcLines = new ArrayList(); // list that contains the A B and C lines.

    //1. We first separate the b lines from the a and c lines by checking whether the field `tlId` of an instance is a `List` or not. We use `Collectors.partitioningBy` to partition the instances based on this condition. The end result is a map holding two lists that can be retrieved with the keys `true` and `false`.
    Map<Boolean, List<ABCLine>> partitionedLines = abcLines.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(abcLine -> abcLine.tlId instanceof List));

    //2. Retrieve the B lines from the map.
    List<ABCLine> separatedBLines = partitionedLines.get(true);
    
    //3. Retrieve the A and C lines from the map.
    List<ABCLine> aAndCLines = partitionedLines.get(false);

    //4. Make a Set containing all the `id` field values from the ready made aline list that you mentioned. This Set will be used to partition the a lines from the c lines. 
    Set<Integer> aLineIds = aLines.stream().map(aLine -> aLine.id).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    //5. We use `Collectors.partitioningBy` again to partition/separate the A lines from the C lines using `aLineIds.contains(line.id)` as the condition. Because the type of the aList id collection is a set we can determine very fast whether the `id` of `line` equals any of the ids in the set.
    Map<Boolean, List<ABCLine>> aAndCMap = aAndCLines.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(line -> aLineIds.contains(line.id)));

    //6. Now you only have to retrieve the A and C lines from the map and you're done.
    List<ABCLine> separatedALines = aAndCMap.get(true);
    List<ABCLine> separatedCLines = aAndCMap.get(false);
```